# check category have child category or not in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have category id .I got the id from this code

```
<?php echo $current_catid=$this->getCategoryId(); ?>
```

**now i want to check that this category have child category or not** .

if it have child than it will show the child category image and name and url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this one, its working fine at my end

```
<?php  
$parentCategoryId = 10;
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId)->getChildren();
$catArray = explode(',', $categories);
foreach($catArray as $child)
{
$_child = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $child );
echo $_child->getName() . '<br />';
echo $_child->getUrl() . '<br />';
echo $_child->getDescription() . '<br />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

If You have current_category id then load category

*`$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(id);`*

and check `count($category->getChildren());`

Other methods are for count children

```
count($category->getChildrenNodes()); 

$category->getChildrenCount();
```

This way you can check if category has children or not.

`getChildren()` methods give you children category id and based on id you can get category image and category name.

Comment: i tried your code but its not working ..its always showing 1 when i count the children but its have 2 child category
i put this code
    $current_catid=$this->getCategoryId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($current_catid);
echo count($category->getChildren());

Comment: Try getChildre()->count() methods instead or you can also use count($category->getChildrenNodes()); for count category children

Comment: i tried this as you told me 
$category->getChildren()->count();
its giving me fatal error

Answer (score 1):

A bit old, but I was searching for the same solution and @Mufaddal's solution didn't work. Then I found `getChildrenCategories()`.

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
count($_category->getChildrenCategories());
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on whether or not the option "Use Flat Catalog Category" is enabled.

Therefore, the best method to check category have child category or not is:

```
if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {
    $childrenCount = $category->getResource()->getChildrenAmount($category);
} else {
    $childrenCount = $category->getResource()->getChildrenCount();
}
```

with $category I suppose you have already, as:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have another option to check category child category exist or not..

```
  <?php
    $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $currentCategoryId);
    $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
    $subCategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getParentId())->getChildrenCategories();

    if($collection->getSize() >= 1){//there some thing....}else{

//Get Subcategory....


foreach ($subCategories as $subCategoryId ): 

                     if($subCategoryId->getIsActive())
                    {  $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId->getId())
                    ->getProductCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);


                        <li <?php if($subCategoryId->getId()==$currentCategoryId){?>class="active"<?php } ?>>
                            <a href="<?php echo $subCategoryId->getURL(); ?>">
                                <?php //echo $subCategoryId->getName()." (".$products->count().")"; ?>
                                <?php echo $subCategoryId->getName(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                      } endforeach;}?>
```

if it's help full let me know...

Thanks 
Ravi